# Error when logging into magento backend

Tags: error, backend, login

I am getting an error that seems to happen randomly when trying to login to Magento backend. Even when I do gain access to backend without error, it takes a very long time.

Any idea what this error is caused by?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:63:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away";i:1;s:2692:"#0 /home/website/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/website/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/website/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/website/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `admin_r...', Array)
#4 /home/website/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `admin_r...', Array)
#5 /home/website/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Acl.php(69): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php(100): Mage_Admin_Model_Resource_Acl->loadAcl()
#8 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php(69): Mage_Admin_Model_Session->login('login_name', 'password', Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Admin_Model_Observer->actionPreDispatchAdmin(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Observer), 'actionPreDispat...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/website/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#12 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(528): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#14 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(408): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#15 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#16 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /home/website/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/website/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:16:"/index.php/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message pretty much says it all `MySQL server has gone away`

Something must be hammering your database which results in queries being queued up, and eventually Mysql giving up and restarting.

Have you been running anything on your store? Re-indexes maybe?

Running `mtop` (or mytop) on your Mysql server will give you more information about the problematic queries.